# Incremental BIOS update or direct update to latest version?

Tags: bios

I have been having some BSOD issues, and one of the recommendations to the *`STOP: Error`* that I have been experiencing is a BIOS update.  I went to ASUS website and found the motherboard I am using P8Z77 and noticed that there are about 5-6 BIOS updates from where the motherboard is currently to the releases available today.

The question I have is what is the best thing to do?  Do I do incremental flashes from the current version on the board all the way up to the presently available BIOS?  Or can one just flash the latest BIOS?

Comment: You can simply flash the latest version. The latest version will contain all the fixes and features that were added in the previous versions.

Comment: You should make that an answer, @Ayan.

Comment: @DanielB yeah I though so first, but then it occurred to me that it is a very simple answer so I just made a comment. I am making it an answer now.

Comment: Good question. On one hand there is a tiny risk that one of the intermediate versions has a bug which could brick some boards. On the other hand the more versions are released the less feasible it is to test every upgrade path, which means by skipping intermediate versions you are more likely to hit a particular combination of old and new version which was never tested by the vendor. I'd look for recommendations from the vendor about which upgrade path to use, and if no recommendations have been provided I'd go straight to the wanted version. Read the release notes on each version first.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply flash the latest version of the BIOS. The firmware is always provided as a full image that overwrites the old one, *not* as a patch, so the latest version will contain all the fixes and features that were added in the previous versions. There is no need for an incremental update.

Comment: Just a word of advice: After any flash always reset the BIOS-settings to "factory default". Then reconfigure them the way you want it to be. Sometimes a new BIOS uses previously configured values in a different way.  Reset to defaults ensures that all settings have a properly defined value (using the internal logic of the new bios version).

Answer (score 0):

May not be correct for all mobos.

My Gigabyte board insists on installing latest chip-set driver first then install F32 and then install F40 but now there is an F50 too(which doesn't say anything about previous bios's which is confusing). Here is what is says,

Note:
1. If you are using Q-Flash Utility to update BIOS, make sure you have updated BIOS to F32 before F40
2. Before update BIOS to F40, you have to install EC FW Update Tool (B19.0517.1 or later version) to avoid 4DIMM DDR incompatibility on 3rd Gen AMD Ryzen™ CPU.

Comment: +1 for a counter proof of the accepted answer and thus showing that the once correct and accepted answer does no longer hold true.